# Django - Having two views in same url

Tags: django

I am making a website in django and in my homepage I want to show the list of my recent blog post and a few blocks below I want to make a simple contact form. The blog and the contact form separately are working fine. But I want to include them in the same page(obviously in the same url).

The views.py is:

```
from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'personal/index.html', {'form': form})
```

If you want to look at the forms.py then :

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
```

The urlpattern in urls.py of my homepage is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(
                                queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:2],
                                template_name="personal/index.html")),
    url(r'^$', views.get_name, name='contact'),
]
```

With this urlpatter the list of blog post shows up perfectly but the contact form doesn't show up. But with the below urlpattern contact form shows up but blog posts doesn't show up.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.get_name, name='contact'),
    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(
                                queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:2],
                                template_name="personal/index.html")),
]
```

I want to make both of these contents show up in the same page. Please help me. If you need any more information then do tell.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have multiple views for the same URL. You can only have one view for each URL.

In this case, the easiest fix is to update your `get_name` view so that it includes the posts in the template context.

```
def get_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = NameForm()
    post_list = Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:2]
    return render(request, 'personal/index.html', {'form': form, 'post_list': post_list})
```

Then remove the url pattern that uses `ListView` so that `get_name` handles the requests.

Comment: this time the contact form appeared but the blog post didn't appear....I think its because the equivalent code to listview(and stuffs) in urls.py in views.py is incorrrect...Please help

Comment: I think it should work if you use `post_list` instead of `posts` as I originally had. You didn't show your template, so I wasn't sure what the template variable name was.

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot do that directly, you could consider your function in views.py to handle the request in a way that when it gets a post request from one model then it initialises the form for the respective model only. For this to happen you will need to assign a name to your button. See below code -

```
def SignUpLogin(request):
    message = ""
    Login_message = ""
    print(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('UserForgotPassword') == 'Sign Up':
            form_SignUP_Login = LoginForm()
            print("POST request received")
            print(request.POST)
            form_SignUP=SignUpForm(request.POST)
            print(form_SignUP)
            if form_SignUP.is_valid():
                if request.POST["Password"] != request.POST["Confirm_Password"]:
                    message = "* Passwords do not match"
                    #raise forms.ValidationError(('Passwords do not match'), code="PasswordNotMatched")
                else:
                    try:
                        user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST["Username"])
                        context= {'form': form_SignUP, 'error':'* Username already taken. Please try different username.'}
                        return render(request, 'User/SignUp.html', context)
                    except User.DoesNotExist:
                        user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST["Username"], request.POST["Email"], request.POST["Password"])
                        user.first_name = request.POST["First_Name"]
                        user.last_name = request.POST["Last_Name"]
                        user.save()
                        form_SignUP = SignUpModel(Username = request.POST["Username"], First_Name = request.POST["First_Name"], Last_Name = request.POST["Last_Name"], Email = request.POST["Email"],  Company_Name = request.POST["Company_Name"], Address = request.POST["Address"], Password = make_password(request.POST["Password"]), Confirm_Password = make_password(request.POST["Confirm_Password"]), Phone_Number = request.POST["Phone_Number"])
                        form_SignUP.save()

                        #queryset = SignUpModel.objects.get(Username = request.POST["Username"])
                        #queryset.Password = "pwd_removed"
                        #queryset.Confirm_Password = "pwd_removed"
                        #queryset.save()
                        #send_email_to_host(request.POST["First_Name"], request.POST["Family_Name"], request.POST["Number_Of_Adults"], request.POST["Number_Of_Kids"], request.POST["Email"])
                        return redirect(HomePage)

        elif request.POST.get('UserLogin') == 'Login':
            form_SignUP = SignUpForm()
            form_SignUP_Login=LoginForm(request.POST)
            if form_SignUP_Login.is_valid():
                user = authenticate(username=request.POST["Username"], password=request.POST["Password"])
                if user is not None:
                    print("User authenticated")
                    return redirect(HomePage)
                else:
                    print("User not authenticated")
                    form_SignUP_Login = LoginForm()
                    Login_message = "Username and password combination is not correct"

        elif request.POST.get('UserForgotPassword') == 'Forgot Password':
            form_SignUP = SignUpForm()
            form_SignUP_Login = LoginForm()


    else:
        form_SignUP = SignUpForm()
        form_SignUP_Login = LoginForm()

    return render(request, 'User/SignUp.html', {'form' : form_SignUP, "error":message,'form_login' : form_SignUP_Login, "error_login":Login_message})
```