# django best way of managing template and it's views

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, django-views, django-urls

In django is it the only way to have only one view for one whole page/url. And whatever functions(upload/post/update/log-in) that page contains just needs to pass inside that view. I found this is the only way as i can only return one url with one view.

I am wondering if there has any way where i can make different view(may be classed base or normal) for each function and at last add all of them on one single view(that view return that url also). If it is possible than how ? Because having all the functions of a url inside one view is looking weird and messy to me.

```
##################
def logInRegisterUser(request):
    ###################login##################
    loginForm = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if loginForm.is_valid() and 'log-in' in request.POST:
        username = loginForm.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = loginForm.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        # if not user or not user.check_password(password):
        #   raise validation error
        login(request, user)
        print(request.user.is_authenticated())

    ###################registration###################
    registrationForm = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if registrationForm.is_valid() and 'sign-up' in request.POST:
        user2 = registrationForm.save(commit = False)
        password2 = registrationForm.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user2.set_password(password2)
        user2.save()

        new_user = authenticate(username = user2.username, password = password2)
        login(request, new_user)

    ###################log-out###################
    ###################search-post###################
    ####################voting-post##################

    context = {
        "loginForm":loginForm,
        "registrationForm":registrationForm,
        "re":request.POST
    }

    ###################return###################
    return render(request,"enter.html",context)
```

Comment: Please give an example of what you have and what should be changed!

Comment: Views.py is just a python file, you can create multiple .py files containing your functions (name the files according to their functionality) and then import them like you would do normally.

Comment: if your views is getting too messy , you could considering writing each functions in a different python file and just importing the method to your views. but by default a single url can have a single view

Comment: @KlausD. i have added my code. In one view i had to write all the functions how to separate

Comment: @JohnJosephFernandes it's okay if i have to write all the code in one file.But i need to write them in different function/method.  How at the end all methods i can bring on my main view.

Answer (score 0):

you can merge the response from another class. You can merge multiple class response into to a single view.

[Django - Having two views in same url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493687/django-having-two-views-in-same-url)